# iPhone 5 no phone services

Tags: applecare

I am unable to dial out receive calls or text messages.

How can I fix the problem?

I've tried shutting it down waiting awhile then turning it back on and the phone still shows "searching".

Comment: You may have turned on Airplane Mode (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1355) by accident. Go to Settings to check.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no phone service check following:

- Disable [Airplane mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1355) (if it is enabled)
- Check that your SIM card is inserted properly.
- Check if you see your phone service provider name.